# How to mock entityManager.getTransaction().begin() in Hibernate with Mockito?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, junit, mockito

I'm working on an implementation of a DAO that have to persist an entity, but i'm stuck having to mock the beginning of the transaction.

In particular, i don't know how to mock with Mockito this call:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the piece of code you are trying to unit test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock `entityManager` and make it returning `transaction` mock.

```
public class DaoTest {

  EntityManager entityManager = Mockito.mock(EntityManager.class);
  EntityTransaction transaction = Mockito.mock(EntityTransaction.class);
  Dao dao = new MyDao();

  @Test
  void whenSave_thenBeginTransaction(){
    when(entityManager.getTransaction()).thenReturn(transaction);
    dao.save(new MyObject());
    verify(transaction).begin();
  }            
}
```